# SSIS : How to set the TransactionOption as Expression or in Script Task?

Tags: transactions, ssis, properties, expression

I've tried setting the TransactionOption as an expression on a Sequence Container:

```
@[User::Config_DevelopmentMode] ? DTSTransactionOption.Supported : DTSTransactionOption.Required
```

--> Does not evaluate

```
@[User::Config_DevelopmentMode] "Supported" : "Required"
```

--> Does evaluate, but gives error : The result of the expression cannot be written to TransactionOtion

Any hints ?

I've also tried to change the TransactionOption in a script task, but how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345178%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) help page.

**TransactionOption property**
Set by using values from the DTSTransactionOption enumeration.

```
Friendly name in DTSTransactionOption : Numeric value
NotSupported : 0
Supported : 1
Required : 2
```

So the expression should be:

```
@[User::Config_DevelopmentMode] ? 1 : 2
```